# Asignar a un TextView un campo String

Tags: java, android

Estoy utilizando el siguiente codigo donde quiero darle formato de moneda a un TextView pero el momento de asignar este me sale que el error que es son incompatible el TextView que se require android.widget.TextView y el espera un java.lang.string (Ambos no son texto?)

```
DecimalFormat formato = new DecimalFormat("$#,###");

public class ProductosViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView tvDescripcion;
    TextView tvPrecio;
    TextView tvCantPrd;
    CheckBox cbCarro;

    public ProductosViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        TextView strPlata = formato.format(itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrecio));<----Error
        tvNomProducto =itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvNomProducto);
        tvDescripcion=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDescripcion);
        tvPrecio =  strPlata; 
        cbCarro = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cbCarro);
        tvCantPrd = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCantPrd);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TextView es un control que te permite mostrar un texto. String es una cadena de texto.

Primero debes inicializar el TextView:

```
tvPrecio = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrecio);
```

Y para poner un String en un TextView tienes llamar el método `setText();`

```
tvPrecio.setText(strPlata);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias crrlos, me dio una luz para corrección del error. te lo agradezco mucho.

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias crrlos, me dio una luz para correccion del error. te lo agradezco mucho.

pude hacerlo asi:

```
DecimalFormat formato = new DecimalFormat("$#,###");
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final BebidasViewHolder bebidasViewHolder, final int i) {
        bebidasViewHolder.tvNomProducto.setText(listaBebidas.get(i).getNomProducto());
        bebidasViewHolder.tvDescripcion.setText(listaBebidas.get(i).getDescripcion());
        bebidasViewHolder.tvPrecio.setText(""+formato.format(listaBebidas.get(i).getPrecio()));
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema se debe a que tratas de obtener una referencia del TextView incorrectamente, de hecho no es necesario declarar una variable extra para almacenar la referencia  (strPlata) simplememente obtenla directamente:

```
public ProductosViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    //TextView strPlata = formato.format(itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrecio));<----Error
    tvNomProducto =itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvNomProducto);
    tvDescripcion=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDescripcion);
    tvPrecio = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrecio); //strPlata; 
    cbCarro = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cbCarro);
    tvCantPrd = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCantPrd);
}
```

En realidad lo que deseas es aplicar un formato al texto, debería usarse al obtener el texto,ejemplo:

```
   DecimalFormat formato = new DecimalFormat("$#,###");
   String precio = "12.45";    
   tvPrecio.setText(formato.format(precio));
```